# Not able to install any package in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, java, jdk

I tried to do this:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

Setting up oracle-java6-installer (6u45-0~webupd8~8) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 6...
--2017-10-05 01:37:47--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 123.176.33.9, 123.176.33.24
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|123.176.33.9|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin [following]
--2017-10-05 01:37:47--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 104.81.23.175, 2600:140f:9:193::2d3e, 2600:140f:9:18c::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|104.81.23.175|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin?AuthParam=1507147788_6fa79be97f022ca0824a378f6e4b8796 [following]
--2017-10-05 01:37:48--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin?AuthParam=1507147788_6fa79be97f022ca0824a378f6e4b8796
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|123.176.33.9|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-10-05 01:37:49 ERROR 404: Not Found.

download failed
Oracle JDK 6 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java6-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java6-installer
```

I did downloaded packages from oracle java but still I get this error if I tried to update or install any software.
How to solve this?

Comment: Can you try cleaning the apt cache then try running that command again. Use `sudo apt-get autoremove; sudo apt-get clean`

Comment: sudo apt-get autoremove shows again same oracle-java6 error.For any package installation it tries to download oracle java6 but it cannot get permission from oracle so it gets failed. How to control this behaiour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Oracle has decided to remove the binaries of Java 7 and 6, therefore caused the error to pop.

Actually, you can get Oracle Java 6 and 7 if you have an Oracle Support Account (which is not free).

What are you trying to do is install the `oracle-java6-installer` provided from [webupd8](http://webupd8.org), but they stopped distributing their installer because of this issue.

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html

#### To prevent Oracle Java installer from appear on every install/update

You need to remove the broken installation, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java6-installer
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I know this and I followed this http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux to get rid of any openjdk before I reinstall java from oracle. In step 3 it says to purge all openjdk/jre files, and I did that. I proceeded and installed java9 yesterday, but again if I do sudo apt-get anything, it tried to download and install openjdk-6. I do not want this to happen.

Comment: Sorry, updated solution. Didn't read question carefully.

Comment: With this command I did  not faced this issue again.